# Sending ArrayBuffer as JSON to PHP server

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

I am trying to send a POST request to PHP which will contain an object that has ArrayBuffer element. When I JSON decode the element both ArrayBuffers objects are null/empty.

A "key" object contains 2 ArrayBuffer elements a "p256dh" and a "auth"

The object is generated by pushSubscription object created when registering a service worker.

Subscription variable:

```
{"endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/dgoXscLGNKM:APA91bFcHhA2pGiatLbrhFW08oevNS81LX7C0a0zW3RP7BaJgBhij2apFxtfo8kX_kt5QE6bu5-zoYkpw50GYqOnalpFHYfpECgmIMgpVWcKGRsvUkgzM0aK_9X9HHmPIw7nqDoGK6FQ","expirationTime":null,"keys":{"p256dh":"BDQLzb281Nlw-wQzqYELodphecu7jiZD1sRd_iOCMLvK1u20Bl2-hx5EeyzEpJ0WqYvmRXnddwQHSpfC8PjEghQ","auth":"K3DI2PLDfJSAJC2DMKSqzw"}}
```

Code:

```
 function sendSubscriptionToBackEnd(subscription, end_point)
      {
          return fetch (end_point, { method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body: JSON.stringify(subscription)})                                                                                                       
              .then((res) => {
                  return res.json();
              })
              .then((resJSON) =>{
                  return resJSON;
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                  console.log('Fetch Error : ', err);
              });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution
When creating a pushSubscription object before passing it to fetch I needed to turn it into JSON. IT created a correct string I needed to pass back to back end server.